# getting user input from form using express js and body parser

Tags: node.js, forms, body-parser

I am having problems getting user input from form.
could you please tell where am I going wrong??

here's the add-employee.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Employee</title>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<table>
<form action="/form"  method="post">
<tr>
<th>
<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name">
</th>
<th>
<label>Designation:</label>
<input type="text" name="designation">
</th>
<th>
<label>PAN No:</label>
<input type="text" name="pan">
</th>
<th>
<label>Aadhar No:</label>
<input type="text" name="aadhar">
</th>
<th>
<label>Bank A/c:</label>
<input type="text" name="bank">
</th>
<th>
<label>Basic Salary:</label>
<input type="text" name="basicsalary">
</th>
<th>
<label>Other Allowance:</label>
<input type="text" name="allowance">
</th>
<th>
<label>ESI No:</label>
<input type="text" name="esi">
</th>
<th>
<label>UAN No:</label>
<input type="text" name="uan">
</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="submit" name="submit_button">
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>


</body>


</html>
```

And here's the link to the server.js code which I am using to run the app.
https://github.com/silentarrowz/payroll/blob/master/server.js
when I submit the form I am expecting to get a response of 
'employee' + name + 'added'

But I am getting the result as " employee undefined added ".

now, why is this happening?
where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your server.js you have the line.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

This means that your server can only read JSON data in requests. However, unless you are using javascript/jquery to send the form to the server, the data is never formatted as JSON. Instead browsers use urlencoded or multipart formats to send the form. multipart is normally only used when you are sending files with your form so it is most likely using urlencoded format.

That means that you need to include a body parser for the urlencoded format.

Simply change it so we have the urlencoded parser below the json parser like this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

However if you will be sending files with your forms, you must parse the request using a module like [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty#readme).

Comment: ok, I have done that
and now when I click the submit button I see this in the url bar - http://localhost:8080/form
and the page says The localhost page isn’t working

localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: Thats because you arent sending a response in the post() method. At the bottom in it add res.status(200).send(); to get a response.

Comment: ok, I am a bit confused. 
I had put res.send('employee' + name +'added'); 
In there earlier, 
so isnt that considered a response?

Comment: anyways, i'll try it now

Comment: ok, I have done that now and I am still getting the same error.

Another thing that I noticed is that the browser status bar keeps showing 
"Waiting for local host "for a long time after I have clicked on the submit button.
dont know why that is

Comment: That is because it is waiting for a response, then when it doesnt get one it times out and gives you an error. Anyway, upload the latest verslon of your code to git so I can see what it looks like.

Comment: ok, did that now
here's the link again - https://github.com/silentarrowz/payroll/blob/master/server.js

Comment: You are putting the res.send() in the incorrect place. The form posts to /form not /add-employee.html. Put the console log and res.send below line 32.

Comment: ah, yes.
It is working now. Thanks.
But I am a little confused about this 
I am also doing the app.post for add-employee.html
as well as app.post for /form

could you help me out in what is the job of each one?

Comment: The action attribute in the html form contains the path the form will send to. The reason you have to use /form is because thats whats in the action attribute. If you want to use /add-employee.html put that in the action attribute and then you can remove the /form code. Also, you shouldnt put the .html extensions in the names of yout express routes. Just name it add-employee. It just causes confusion if you keep it this way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133457/discussion-between-faraz-and-grimurd).